# How do I execute this redirect based on whether or not authentication takes place in a Angular 9 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication

Im am working on an Angular 9 application that uses **OneLogin** for authentication purposes.

In the auth.component.ts file I have an authentication service that I use in the authentication component:

```
import { AuthService } from 'path/to/core/services/auth/auth.service';
import { AuthApiService } from 'path/to/core/core/services/auth/auth-api.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { authCodeFlowConfig } from 'path/to/config/onelogin-api/config-auth.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'auth',
    templateUrl: './assets/auth.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./assets/auth.component.scss']
})

export class AuthComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {
    }

    startAuthentication() {
        this._authService.startAuthentication();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.startAuthentication();
    }
}
```

In auth.service.ts I have the `startAuthentication()` method:

```
startAuthentication(): Observable<any> {
    const {issuer, redirectUri, clientId, responseType, scope} = authCodeFlowConfig;

    const url = `someURL`;

    this.redirectTo(url);

    return of(false);
}
redirectTo(url: string): void {
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

In the app.module.ts file I have this array of routes:

```
import { AuthService } from './core/services/auth/auth.service';
// more imports

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path      : 'myroute',
        redirectTo: 'myroute'
    },
    {
        path: 'auth',
        component: AuthComponent
    }
];
```

In other words, I want the application to *reach a certain url if login is successful* and otherwise redirect to the login form.

What I want to happen is: when login is sucessful - in other words, when `startAuthentication()` is executed - there should be a redirect to `myroute`.

I tried `{path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent, startAuthentication:[AuthService]}` bit it fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I don't have any further information about your `StartAuthentication` method, I'd say that you should inject the router service in your component and navigate using it:

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
...

constructor(
  private _authService: AuthService,
  private _router: Router) {}

startAuthentication() {
  this._authService.startAuthentication();
  this._router.navigate(['/', 'myroute']);
}
```

Comment: I get a `Cannot find name 'ActivatedRoute' ts(2304)` error. Also, should I import anything up top?

Comment: Thinking of it again, you don't need `ActivatedRoute`. You'd need it if you was trying to navigate using relative paths, but we're using absolute path on `navigate` method (the path starts with a forward slash). If you needed it, you could import it from `@angular/router` though.

Comment: Could you change your code, in accordance with your comment? Thanks!

Comment: That's the exact reason I've started with "As I don't have any further information...". Give more details, like the code in `this._authService.startAuthentication()`. BTW, I've built a schematics project that can scaffold a login module for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@julianobrasil/schematics-components

Comment: Yeah... the `redirectTo(url);` method... what does it do?

Comment: The redirect mehod does: `window.location.href = url;`; I have added it to the question.

Comment: That's the problem... by doing that, you're reloading your entire application, so the line after the service calling (with the `this._router.navigate(['/', 'myroute']);`) is never executed. Inside a SPA you can't use a `window.location.href` redirect, or use a `<a></a>` in a regular way, or you're gonna reload the app. To stay inside the app, you should stick to angular's router.

Comment: Bit I need that url, because it contains a token. The *authentication* needs it.

Comment: When you load an @angular app all the interactions with the server, including authenticating/grabbing a token should take place using `HttpClientModule`. But if I'm getting right what you're trying to do, it seems like a redirection to an authentication server (maybe an oauth server) and you're counting on the server to load your app again and give you the token, is that right? If you have the token, you go to one route and, if don't, you would use the `window.location.href` redirection to get one.

Comment: Yes, That's about it. But I have not found very good examples, so I don't quite know how to do that.

Comment: I'll do some testing and get back to you. I have a child demanding some attention over here. Just tell me... the token will be sent with a readonly cookie or in the header of the response of the redirection?

Comment: I shouldn't touch that `url` variable, because some othrt guy did it and wants it kept. I should only do a front-end redirect.

Comment: But to decide if you need redirection, you must inspect somewhere to check if you already have the token or if you need to go to the server to get one. How do you plan to check for an existing token to decide if you need redirection or not?